# Combine two excel files with different information for the same SampleID to yield one excel file with one row with ALL info for each SampleID

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel files that contain information for the same SampleIDs -- one file is location information, the other is clinical information. I want to combine the two files into a third, such that each Sample row contains its respective information from each of the original files.

File 1

| SampleID | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Fridge |
| 102 | Freezer |

- File 2

| SampleID | Diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | None |
| 102 | Tumor |

--> File 3

| SampleID | Diagnosis | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | None | Fridge |
| 102 | Tumor | Freezer |

I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df1 = pd.read_excel('Sample Storage.xlsx')
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_excel('Sample log.xlsx')
print(df2)

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=False)
print(df3)

df3.to_excel('CombinedSamples.xlsx')
```

But get an excel file that has two rows for the same SampleID - first row contains location, second row contains diagnosis.

Thoughts on how to combine the rows by SampleID and keep all the data?

Comment: You probably want to [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) instead of concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Given two dataframes as shown below:

```
df1 = 

SampleId    Location
0   101 Fridge
1   102 Freezer  

df2 = 

SampleId    Diagnosis
0   101 None
1   102 Tumor  

df3 = df1.merge(df2)  

Yields:
    SampleId    Location    Diagnosis
0   101 Fridge  None
1   102 Freezer Tumor
```

Comment: Is that because it's matching the 0 and the 1? I want it to match the sample IDs without concern for their location in the original data frame.

Comment: It is merging the files using the sampleid field as key.  I don't know what you mean by without concern for their location?  Please clarify.